# JAVA: JUNIT testing reading from file method class arrays

Tags: java, arrays, junit

How do I test arrays that are of a class type? I have done research and understand the assertArray lang but am unsure as to how to do it when the array is not string

```
  @Test
        public void testReadProductDataFile() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("readProductDataFile");
            File inputFile = new File("ProductData.txt");
            Product[] expResult = null;
            Product[] result = InputFileData.readProductDataFile(inputFile);
            assertArrayEquals(expResult, result);
            // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
            fail("The test case is a prototype.");
        }
```

This method itself reads information from a text file, splits it up into a Product array.
Finished

```
 public void testReadProductDataFile() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("readProductDataFile");
        File inputFile = new File("ProductData.txt");
        Product[] expResult = { new Product("PA/1234",153),new Product("PV/5732",25),
            new Product("Au/9271",172),new Product("DT/9489",95)
                ,new Product("HY/7195",235),new Product("ZR/7413",159)
                ,new Product("bT/4674",725),new Product("LR/4992",629)
                ,new Product("Xk/8536",112),new Product("kD/9767",559)};
        Product[] result = InputFileData.readProductDataFile(inputFile);
        assertArrayEquals(expResult, result);
    }
```

Getting this error

```
arrays first differed at element [0]; expected: supplierproject.Product<Product Code: PA/1234
Price Per Unit: 153.0
> but was: supplierproject.Product<Product Code: PA/1234
Price Per Unit: 153.0
>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at supplierproject.InputFileDataTest.testReadProductDataFile(InputFileDataTest.java:55)
```

I can't see the difference and its not allowing me to view the difference like it does sometimes..

Comment: there is no difference if arrays are of type String or any other. Your code is valid (except `expResult` should be initialised)

Comment: how would I initialise it? the only way I can think is to add a string of the output I think would be added to the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference if arrays are of type String or any other. Your code is valid.

Except `expResult` should be initialised, e.g.

```
Product[] expResult = { new Product("product 1"), new Product("product 2") };
```

and `ProductData.txt` file should contains data which would be read to the similar products (`assertArrayEquals` compare items using `equals()` method).

Comment: Thank you man! literally couldn't find any documentation on this!

Comment: make sure you have `equals()` method in Product class, which compares both Code and Price.